# how do I know which id-scope I'm in?

Tags: jquery

I have some divs with similar content and links, images etc request extended jQuery-functions.

The divs have unique id's but their content have similar fields and structure.

For example, the HTML is:

```html
 <div id="bar1">
   <some xhtml><input type="textbox" class="searchTxt" />
   <some xhtml><img class="notify" src="blank.gif" />
 </div>
 <div id="bar2">
   <some xhtml><input type="textbox" class="searchTxt" />
   <some xhtml><img class="notify" src="blank.gif" />

 ...
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.searchTxt').click(function(obj) {
    //now here I want to know which searchTxt that was clicked,
    //so I can change the img-source..
    //without parent().parent() that may fail since div-content may vary.
});
```

EDIT:
It's partly a poor example, since the jQuery doesn't modify anyting, and this is always available..
Imagine an image in both divs that should be hidden by the click-function.
Example updated.

What's the right path here?

Comment: Give all the top level divs the same class and call `$(this).closest('.theClass').prop('id')`.

Comment: Do not forget to approve the response that best suit you. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `closest()` with a selector:

> ```
> $('.searchTxt').click(function(obj) {
>     alert($(this).closest("div[id^='bar']").prop("id"));
> });
> ```
>
> **Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/bR3xv/1/**

Alternatively, you could add the event handler to the `<div>` element and allow the events to propagate to it.  `event.target` would refer to the text element and `this` would refer to the div:

> ```
> $('div[id^="bar"]').click(function (evt) {
>     if (evt.target.className == "searchTxt")
>         alert(this.id);
> });
> ```
>
> **Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/bR3xv/**

Answer (score 4):

Use `$(this)` for textbox and `$(this).parents("div")` to find the parent div.

Example:

```
$(".searchTxt").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents("div").attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `closest` function to get to the enclosing `<div>` element.

```
$(this).closest('div')
```

This however has a problem when the input is contained within another div in the actual div that you want to locate. To prevent this, you can add a class to ensure that you get to the correct one.

```
$(this).closest('div.search')
```